Module not found: Can't resolve './useListChangeNotifiers'
I am learning how to use Mui, started to try DataGrid things, but when I copy the code from Mui website this error appeard. I have already tried to install this package but didn't work.
<div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        initialState={{
          pagination: {
            paginationModel: { page: 0, pageSize: 5 },
          },
        }}
        pageSizeOptions={[5, 10]}
        checkboxSelection
      />
    </div>```


Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow, please provide a minimal reproducible example.
